# TempData lost on page reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use TempData to store login user role but after the user logs in and presses F5 to reload the page, I run into an error stating that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I use TempData because my page needs redirection. 
The user fills in the login form before submitting it, I don't know how to retrieve the posted data since I need to redirect the user to admin page in case his role is `administrator` or just `standard` page in case his is `normal user`.

```
    private bool IsAdmin(string username)
    {
        return (Roles.GetRolesForUser(username).ToList().Contains("administrator"));
    }

    public ActionResult AdminLayout() 
    {            
        if(IsAdmin(TempData["LoginUsername"].ToString())) //Error TempDate on Reload
        {
             return View();
        } 
        else
        {
             return Index();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you store it in a session variable? As the name suggests, TempData is only temporary and session variables will hold the data for longer.

Comment: Thank you but why does reloading delete the object data ? I think after logging in I am already authenticated and live with TempDate but reloading kills the TempData while my login status remains

Comment: TempData is a session-backed temporary storage dictionary that is available for one single request. http://flux88.com/2008/01/testing-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc/